# Transforming a Microsoft Access table into CSV and/or Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, ms-access, export-to-csv

I have a Microsoft Access table with over 600,000 rows and 111 columns.  All I need to do is obtain this table in .csv format (to convert to a Pandas df) or directly into a Pandas dataframe. I have tried the following:

1. Export the table into .xlsx format. This gives me a worksheet with over 500,000 kb of data, but is completely blank when I open it up.
2. Export the data to .txt. I've done this but it looks like there is an issue with delimiters / inconsistent formatting in the table that pulls data that gets botched by the time you reach the later columns (i.e. some columns are all nulls when they shouldn't be when I pull the .txt into Pandas)
3. Messed around a little bit with the pyodbc package, but I've been able to mainly find information relating to getting Python into access or manipulating an Access database via pyodbc.

To be clear, I am not looking to manipulate or associate with this database, I strictly want to obtain the raw data so I can run it through a Random Forest model I built in Python. Forgive me if any of my phrasing is incorrect / wonky, I've never used Access prior to today.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are exporting that incorrectly, you can check that here: [https://helpcenter.volusion.com/en/articles/424479-how-to-transfer-data-between-microsoft-access-and-your-volusion-store#:~:text=Within%20Access%2C%20select%20the%20database,the%20following%20pop%2Dup%20window](https://helpcenter.volusion.com/en/articles/424479-how-to-transfer-data-between-microsoft-access-and-your-volusion-store#:%7E:text=Within%20Access%2C%20select%20the%20database,the%20following%20pop%2Dup%20window).

then open that using panda:

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

more options for csv using panda: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html